# How to customize the template of BitBagCmsPlugins with Sylius 1.9?

Tags: sylius

I’ve a problem with BitBagCmsPlugins on Sylius 1.9.

I can’t customize the template of thhis plugins. I’ve tried all path:

- in my theme: themes/myTheme/BitBagCmsPlugins/...
- in template of my theme: themes/myTheme/templates/bundle/BitBagCmsPlugins/...
- in bundle of my theme: themes/myTheme/templates/bundle/BitBagCmsPlugins/...

anything change the template are not override.

Someone has the same problem ? Or maybe some can told me another solution ?

Comment: It's `bundles` instead of `bundle` and `BitBagSyliusCmsPlugin` instead of `BitBagCmsPlugins`, so the full path is `themes/myTheme/templates/bundles/BitBagSyliusCmsPlugin/...`.

Comment: thanks for your help and in fact the problem cames below of my path.
The correct path is: themes/mytheme/templates/bundles/BitBagSyliusCmsPlugin/Shop/....
(I'll put a views between BitBag and Shop folder)

Answer (score 0):

For people has the same problem, here my correction:

Careful of your path, when you want to customized a plugin or a bundle with your theme, the path it's:

```
themes/[Your theme]/templates/bundles/[bundleName or plubginName]/....
```